# Update statement issue in ASP.Net website

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to create an update statement for an assignment where the User can alter their account information. Whenever I attempt it, I get an error stating "Syntax error in update statement." I'm adapting the code for generating this statement from another assignment, where the code does work, so I'm sure I must be missing some small detail. Below is the code that I have for the button click that initiates the method that creates the update statement, as well as the method itself.

Button click:

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool userUpdateError = false;


        string tempPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Programmaholics.mdb");
        clsDataLayer myDataLayer = new clsDataLayer(tempPath);


        try
        {
            myDataLayer.UpdateUser(lblUsername.Text, lblCity.Text, lblState.Text, lblFavorite.Text, lblLeastFavorite.Text, lblDate.Text, Convert.ToInt32(UserID.Text));
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            userUpdateError = true;
            string message = "Error updating user, please check form data. ";
            Master.UserFeedBack.Text = message + error.Message;
        }

        if (!userUpdateError)
        {
            Master.UserFeedBack.Text = "Customer Updated Successfully.";
        }
    }
```

Update method:

```
 public void UpdateUser(string userName, string city, string state, string favorite, string leastFavorite, string date, int userID)
    {

        dbConnection.Open();


        string sqlStmt = "UPDATE tblUser SET Username = @user, " +
          "City = @city, " +
          "State = @state, " +
          "Favorite = @favorite, " +
          "LeastFavorite @least, " +
          "DateLast = @date " +
          "WHERE (tblUser.UserID = @id)";

        OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlStmt, dbConnection);


        OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("@user", userName);
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@city", city));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@state", state));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@favorite", favorite));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@least", leastFavorite));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@date", date));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", userID));


        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        dbConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `=` is missing in the `"LeastFavorite @least, " +`, it should be `"LeastFavorite = @least, " +`

Comment: I knew it was going to be something small like that. *facepalm* Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

change "WHERE (tblUser.UserID = @id)" to "WHERE UserID = @id" because you are trying update same table, it´s not necessary.

```
string sqlStmt = "UPDATE tblUser SET Username = @user, " +
          "City = @city, " +
          "State = @state, " +
          "Favorite = @favorite, " +
          "LeastFavorite @least, " +
          "DateLast = @date " +
          "WHERE UserID = @id";
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in [Arulkumar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463539/update-statement-issue-in-asp-net-website?noredirect=1#comment99518689_56463539):

`=` is missing in the `"LeastFavorite @least, " +,` it should be `"LeastFavorite = @least, " +`